# Objective C - iBeacon locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

I'm trying out iBeacons now.
I have 2 devices that I'm using as beacons and 1 device to do the ranging.

When I implemented this method call locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:, in the documentation it says that "didRangeBeacons" takes an array of beacons in the proximity.

However, what I'm noticing is that locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion: is getting called twice by each individual beacons. Is it supposed to behave that way?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to get one call per second to `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion` for **each** `CLBeaconRegion` that you are ranging, and this callback includes an array of the `CLBeacon` objects that are seen inside that region.

So if you have set up two `CLBeaconRegion` objects and are ranging on both of them, you should two callbacks per second, each with a single beacon in its array.

If you have set up a single `CLBeaconRegion` for ranging that matches both beacons, then you should only get one callback per second and it should contain two beacons in its array.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion` gets called multiple times - when the proximity of beacons changes. I thought I read that this was usually once per second (and my testing would seem to align with this) but I can't find a reference for it at the moment.

You can of course decide what action you want to take whenever the method gets called (or even to take no action at all). You could also call `stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:` if you only want to be notified once.